# Simplificar botões java Alterar+Salvar

Tags: java

Tenho uma aplicação com 6 botões em cada tela, salvar, alterar, novo, deletar, sair, cancelar.

Gostaria de ajuda para juntar dois botões de salvar e alterar em um só, para limpar um pouco minha tela.

Fazer um botão só que faça as duas coisas salvar e alterar, ou seja se o id (que é chave primária no banco de dados da tabela usuario) não existir no sistema criar um cadastro novo(INSERT no banco de dados), caso ele já exista alterar o cadastro(UPDATE no banco de dados), preciso somente da lógica da manipulação do banco de dados, os tratamentos eu me preocupo depois.

Achei vários tópicos na internet mais ainda não intendi a lógica. Uso Postgres + Java. Obrigado!

**ESTA É A AÇÃO QUE O BOTÃO DE ALTERAR FAZ NO MEU CADASTRO DE USUÁRIOS, MAS QUE SEGUE A MESMA LÓGICA QUE USO PARA CADASTRO DE EMPRESAS E FUNCIONÁRIOS**

```
conecta.conexao();
try {            
        PreparedStatement pst = conecta.connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE USUARIO SET SENHA=?,NOME=? WHERE LOGIN=?");            
        pst.setString(1, jPFSenha.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jTNome.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jTLogin.getText());
        pst.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados alterados com Sucesso");

        preencherTabela("select * from USUARIO order by login");//executa o método de preencher os dados na jTable com as informações do banco de dados

    } catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "erro ao alterar dados "+e);
    }
}
```

**BOTÃO SALVAR**

```
conecta.conexao();
if(!jTLogin.getText().equals("") && !jTNome.getText().equals("") && !(String.valueOf(jPFSenha.getPassword()).equals(""))){

        try {

            String SQL = "INSERT INTO usuario(login, senha, nome) VALUES(?,?,?)";


            try (PreparedStatement pst = conecta.connection.prepareStatement(SQL) 
            ) {
                pst.setString(2, String.valueOf(jPFSenha.getPassword()));
                pst.setString(3, jTNome.getText());
                pst.setString(1, jTLogin.getText());
                pst.execute(); 
            } 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados CADASTRADOS com Sucesso");
            preencherTabela("select * from USUARIO order by login");//executa o método de preencher os dados na tabela com as informações do banco de dados
            limpar();//executa o método de limpar os dados do jTextField

        } catch (HeadlessException | SQLException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "erro ao alterar dados "+e);
        }
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Favor preencher o cadastro completo!!");         
    }
```

OBs.: Os dois botões estão funcionando perfeitamente apenas quero que um botão de salvar faça as duas operações de salvar e alterar .

**Segue a minha tela de cadastro de usuário.**

[image: Segue a minha tela de cadastro de usuário.]

Quando o cliente clica na  linha da tabela os dados aparecem no jTextField, então o  programa usa os dados do jTextField para alterar os dados no banco de dados, quando o cliente clica no botão novo, limpo todos os dados do jTextField e  ao clicar em salvar o sistema grava um novo cadastro no banco de dados, então eu queria que  o sistema fizesse uma verificação se o cadastro informado já existisse no banco de dados ele fizesse um update e caso o não existisse fazer um insert. Não consigo deixar mais claro que isso, caso ainda falte alguma informação por favor me avise.

Comment: Por favor, acesse o link e adicione um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel analisar melhor o problema.

Comment: Desculpe mais uma vez, fiz as edições necessárias, acho que agora conseguirão entender o que preciso.

Comment: Ainda não vejo um [mcve]. Você espera dicas de melhorias mas não apresenta um codigo executável. Entende como torna dificil qualquer dica?

Answer (score 1):

Douglas, com a estrutura que você tem agora o mais fácil é fazer uma function no banco de dados que receba por parâmetro seu login, nome e senha e o banco de dados "se vira" com os dados. Crie uma function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION upsert_usuario(loginParam TEXT, nomeParam TEXT, senhaParam) 
RETURNS VOID AS
$$
BEGIN
    LOOP
        -- tenta atualizar o registro
        UPDATE usuario SET nome = nomeParam, senha = senhaParam WHERE login=loginParam;
        IF found THEN
            RETURN;
        END IF;
        -- se não encontrou nenhum registro continua a execução do loop
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO usuario(login, nome, senha) VALUES (loginParam, 
nomeParam, senhaParam);
            RETURN;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Deixe apenas um botão pra fazer a chamada da function passando os parâmetros, pra fazer a chamada coloque este sql

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT upsert_usuario(?,?,?)";
```

Desse modo executando a query o banco de dados resolve de insere ou atualiza os dados.