# Se existir dados no mysql fazer um update PHP/MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

Galera, imagino que essa dúvida seja recorrente. Até busquei algumas alternativas porém não funcionaram.

Eu tenho uma Tela onde gravo Ordens de Serviço com os dados de Cliente e do PC dele. Acontece que. Estou preenchendo 2 Tabelas simultaneamente.

Na tabela `tb_os` eu gravo As ordens de Serviço propriamente dito(completa). E na tabela `clientes` eu gravo apenas as informações do cliente caso eu queira fazer apenas minha lista de clientes(que posso usar em outros lugares do meu sisteminha).

Porém como minha tabela de clientes já está ficando um pouco grande, eu não queria ficar toda hora correndo risco de cadastrar o mesmo cliente, com mesmo nome, endereço etc.

Meu código funcional é esse:

```
 $sql = " insert into tb_os (os_status, cliente, telefone, celular, email, endereco, endereco_num, complemento, bairro, cep, tipo, marca, modelo, processador, memoria, hd, acompanha, ordem_servico )";
$sql.= " values ( '$os_status', '$cliente', '$telefone', '$celular', '$email', '$endereco', '$numero', '$complemento', '$bairro', '$cep', '$tipo', '$marca', '$modelo', '$processador', '$memoria', '$hd', '$acompanha', '$texto_os' ) ";

sql2 = " INSERT INTO clientes (cliente, email) VALUES ('$cliente', '$email') ";

 if (mysqli_query($link, $sql) AND mysqli_query($link, $sql2)){ 
    $mail = $email;     
    $to = $email;
```

Onde concluo com um envio do email pro cliente. Até aí certinho preenchendo as 2 tabelas.

Ai tentei isso para evitar que não ficasse populando com informações repetidas:

```
if(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE cliente = '".$cliente."'")) {
    $sql2 = "UPDATE clientes Set cliente = '".$cliente."', telefone = '".$telefone."' WHERE cliente = '".$cliente."' ";
} else {
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO clientes (cliente, telefone) VALUES ('".$cliente."', '".$telefone."')";
}
```

Porém ao fazer isso, ele simplesmente ignora meu pedido de `update` em `clientes` e faz o cadastro da tabelas `tb_os` de forma normal.

Nessas tabelas como chaves primárias eu tenho `id_os` em `tb_os` e `id_cliente` em `clientes`. Mas não sei se isso ajuda de alguma forma.

Alguém consegue me dar uma luz? Alguma forma de conferir se o registro com nome Cliente já existe, se existir apenas fazer update?

Abraço galera e bom restinho de Domingo se tiver alguém passeando por aqui hoje kkkk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

essa não é o função correta de verificar se já existe na tabela. A função correta é essa:

```
mysqli_num_rows()
```

Como ficaria?

```
if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE cliente = '".$cliente."'")) > 0) {
    $sql2 = "UPDATE clientes SET cliente = '".$cliente."', telefone = '".$telefone."' WHERE cliente = '".$cliente."' ";
} else {
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO clientes (cliente, telefone) VALUES ('".$cliente."', '".$telefone."')";
}
```

Fonte: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp)

Comment: Ah verdade, poderia ter feito a consulta verificando numero de linhas. Valeu meu caro funcionou de maneira muito boa.

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde Rafael! Sempre tem aquele momento depois do almoço da família que todo mundo dorme, então a gente aproveita pra dar uma sapeada por aqui kkk
Olha, a sua problemática é parecida com uma que respondi a alguns dias, sugeri que fosse criada uma função no banco de dados que tente fazer update no registro e se não tiver afetado nada, fizesse a inserção. Isso faz com que a aplicação apenas precise chamar a função no banco de dados  e o banco de dados  se vira com a solução da problemática. A resolução no post está em PostgreSQL, faça uma dessa para MySQL que vai dar certo também. Se precisar de ajuda pra montar a função me manda um comentário aqui que eu altero quando tiver acesso a um pc, agora estou pelo celular.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/245627/51460

Comment: Programador realmente tem um relógio diferenciado kkkkkk
Acabei usando a dica do Léo, pois ainda não manjo de funções de banco de dado. Mas já peguei o link aqui para estudar, pois a ideia é muito boa (E prática também, até para um código mais completo).
Valeu pela ajuda Renan. Tenha uma ótima semana!